# Open a link in phone's default browser from phonegap inappbrowser

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I have a cakephp website, its build in jQuery Mobile(JQM). Now I want to build it as a app so I used Phonegap and I open my web url in Phonegap Cordova inappbrowser. Its working fine for now. Speed etc. all are good according to client. Problem is that my web have some external links also like facebook, twitter etc. So when I click on any external link it opens url in my app (inappbrowser). But I want to open in phone's default browser. Means If iPhone then open in Safari and if Android then open in Chrome.
I have used Phonegap Cordova cli-5.2.0.
Thanks

Comment: try adding "_system" to your external links in the pages?

Comment: I tried "_system", "_blank" and tried by `window.open('URL','_system')` also but did not solve my problem...... Is there any plugin or access permission which we need to add to work this??

Comment: How about using `ref.addEventListener(eventname, callback);` , send an event function to check if `a` tags are clicked and then fire `exit` and then fire `window.open(arg, '_system')`. Reason doing this is that, links inside inAppbrowser opens in the same window even if you use `_system`. So idea is to exit the inappbrowser with an argument passed back to the app on exit event and then run window.open with '_system'. Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks Giri...It works as I want....only one issue..I added below code `if(event.url.match("google.com")) {
ref.close();
window.open(event.url,'_system');
}`
problem is that it close app and open url in chrome its fine but when i open app its open my first page but I want to open my page from where I have clicked. Means is there any way that app only minimize not close. Thanks again!!

Comment: Use localStorage or SessionStorage to store the anchor href when exit fires and run `ref.close(); window.open(localStorage.getItem('url'), '_system');`

Comment: LocalStorage will get last url...I mean when I used `ref.close()` then it will close app and when I open app next time it will open apps home page not the page from where I have clicked on external link because app is closed. so when app is open it will open its home page but if we can app only minimize then it will open previous page.....so is there any way that we don't close app, only minimize app and open external link into default/system browser.

Comment: i meant to say use `localStorage.setItem('url', toSaveUrl);` and then `ref.close()` fires, use a callback to run `window.open(localStorage.getItem('url', '_system);`. Do you understand this?

Comment: yes i understand you want to say that store external link in local storage and then open that url using `window.open()` but I want to say that when i open app again then how i'll open page in app from where i have clicked external link. Let me explain suppose dashboard is my home page and i click on external link from my_profile page. its close app and open link in system browser. its fine. now when I opn app again it show me dashboard(home page) but should be open my_profile page. Its show me dashboard because whenever app start its open dashboard inappbrowser. Please help...

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to here. Are you trying to emulate a website as an app by not locally storing the rendered pages inside the app?

Comment: Yes, as i have explained in my question also i have opening a website in inappbrowser so it looks like app.